# Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Base.AppCompat.DialogWhenLarge.Base'

Tags: android

```
[2014-11-22 07:46:34 - aa] D:\EclipseAndroidWorkspace\Leaning_exercise\appcompat_v7\res\values-large-v14\themes_base.xml:19: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Base.AppCompat.DialogWhenLarge.Base'.
[2014-11-22 07:46:34 - aa] D:\EclipseAndroidWorkspace\Leaning_exercise\appcompat_v7\res\values-large-v14\themes_base.xml:22: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Base.AppCompat.Light.DialogWhenLarge.Base'.
[2014-11-22 08:04:40 - aaa] D:\EclipseAndroidWorkspace\Leaning_exercise\appcompat_v7\res\values-large-v14\themes_base.xml:19: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Base.AppCompat.DialogWhenLarge.Base'.
[2014-11-22 08:04:40 - aaa] 
[2014-11-22 08:04:40 - aaa] D:\EclipseAndroidWorkspace\Leaning_exercise\appcompat_v7\res\values-large-v14\themes_base.xml:22: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Base.AppCompat.Light.DialogWhenLarge.Base'.
[2014-11-22 08:04:40 - aaa] 
[2014-11-22 08:04:41 - aaa] D:\EclipseAndroidWorkspace\Leaning_exercise\appcompat_v7\res\values-large-v14\themes_base.xml:19: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Base.AppCompat.DialogWhenLarge.Base'.
[2014-11-22 08:04:41 - aaa] 
[2014-11-22 08:04:41 - aaa] D:\EclipseAndroidWorkspace\Leaning_exercise\appcompat_v7\res\values-large-v14\themes_base.xml:22: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Base.AppCompat.Light.DialogWhenLarge.Base'.
[2014-11-22 08:04:41 - aaa] 
[2014-11-22 08:04:44 - aaa] D:\EclipseAndroidWorkspace\Leaning_exercise\appcompat_v7\res\values-large-v14\themes_base.xml:19: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Base.AppCompat.DialogWhenLarge.Base'.
[2014-11-22 08:04:44 - aaa] 
[2014-11-22 08:04:44 - aaa] D:\EclipseAndroidWorkspace\Leaning_exercise\appcompat_v7\res\values-large-v14\themes_base.xml:22: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Base.AppCompat.Light.DialogWhenLarge.Base'.
[2014-11-22 08:04:44 - aaa] 
[2014-11-22 08:07:16 - aaa] D:\EclipseAndroidWorkspace\Leaning_exercise\appcompat_v7\res\values-large-v14\themes_base.xml:19: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Base.AppCompat.DialogWhenLarge.Base'.
[2014-11-22 08:07:16 - aaa] 
[2014-11-22 08:07:16 - aaa] D:\EclipseAndroidWorkspace\Leaning_exercise\appcompat_v7\res\values-large-v14\themes_base.xml:22: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Base.AppCompat.Light.DialogWhenLarge.Base'.
[2014-11-22 08:07:16 - aaa]
```

I searched the Internet for servral days,but found no proper answer, help me!!! Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- First Open SDK Manager and make sure that "Android Support  Library" under "Extras" is installed there.
- inside your work space remove "appcompat_v7" from eclipse and also its directory permanently
- File|Import|Android(Existing Android Code into Workspace) then Hit Next
- Choose Root directory as "ADT_BUNDLE_INSTALLED_DIRECTORY\sdk\extras\android\support\v7" then under projects check "appcompat" then hit "Finish"
- Right Click on your project and hit "properties" and do the following:

  1. from "Android" section, make sure target is selected there below there there is "library" section remove the old one and browse for the new one "appcompat_v7"
  2. from "Java Build Path" section, go to "libraries" tab and remove any missing library if you found any.
  3. from "Java Build Path" section, go to "Order and Export" tab and highlight only for the following and keep the same order:

     - projectName/src
     - projectName/gen
     - Android Private Libraries
     - Android Dependecies
  4. from "Project References" section, check "appcompat_v7"

However it is complicated but I have fixed it like this .. hope yours too .. good luck

Comment: Nice to hear that ..  Hope to mark as correct answer to help community .. good luck