# Android System Cleaning App Open Source

Tags: android, system

I'm trying to translate [this](https://github.com/joyoyao/superCleanMaster) open source project and make it my own but I'm running into errors when trying to clean or rebuild. I need help figuring out what I need to do.

Here's my error list:

```
/Users/Technologx/Desktop/Android Projects/New/SysVac/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values/values.xml
Error:(413) Multiple substitutions specified in non-positional format; did you mean to add the formatted="false" attribute?
Error:(413) Unexpected end tag string
Error:(413) Multiple substitutions specified in non-positional format; did you mean to add the formatted="false" attribute?
Error:(413) Unexpected end tag string
/Users/Technologx/Desktop/Android Projects/New/SysVac/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-large-v4/values-large-v4.xml
Error:(12) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.FixedSize'.
Error:(13) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.FixedSize'.
Error:(12) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.FixedSize'.
Error:(13) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.FixedSize'.
/Users/Technologx/Desktop/Android Projects/New/SysVac/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v11/values-v11.xml
Error:(66) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat'.
Error:(67) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog'.
Error:(68) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
Error:(66) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat'.
Error:(67) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog'.
Error:(68) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
/Users/Technologx/Desktop/Android Projects/New/SysVac/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v21/values-v21.xml
Error:(66) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat'.
Error:(140) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
Error:(66) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat'.
Error:(140) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

I'm not sure what I'm needing to do to fix these errors. I'm new to Android coding and was going to use this to help me learn.

Here's the [file](https://ghostbin.com/paste/2zev2) that it's wanting me to fix.

Answer (score 0):

1: replace `%s` with `%1$s` all in your string.xml
2: I suggest You use **AndroidStudio** rather than **eclipse** when are you developing Android app. This needs android support library.[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27072530/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name)

Comment: Alright so what about this    Error:(413) Multiple substitutions specified in non-positional format; did you mean to add the formatted="false" attribute?

Comment: other errors maybe because of lack of android support lib,v4 and v7, when you use AndroidStudio make your project ,It can resolve it automatic.

Comment: That's what I'm using and always use I try to rebuild and clean but I get those errors every time.

Comment: Everything worked before I changed package names in the java files and translated the Chinese to English.

Comment: I don't know why  you can't compile it,Just a minute ago ,I try to run this project ,It worked fine.1、My Android Studio version 2.2.3,edit project gradle version 2.14.1,compileSdkVersion 23,   buildToolsVersion "23.0.3".

Comment: Now it's weird I'm running into this: Error:(2) Tag <manifest> attribute package has invalid character ' '.
Error:(2) Tag <manifest> attribute package has invalid character ' '.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt  here's a screen http://upicme.technologx.com/images/ScreenShot2017-01-13at2.11.07AMbfebd.png

Comment: Hi ,I changed package names too,and it still worked fine ,you should edit gradle:compile version 23,build version 23.03 ,applicationid，and the custom view name in layout,menu.xml. You should make sure replace all the "com.yzy.supercleaner" string in your project,and use a higher version gradle and studio.I hope you can resolve it.

Comment: I did all of that now I get Error:(29, 92) error: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6
(use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
/Users/Technologx/Desktop/Android Projects/New/SysVac/library/src/main/java/com/etiennelawlor/quickreturn/library/listeners/SpeedyQuickReturnRecyclerViewOnScrollListener.java
Error:(33, 89) error: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6
(use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
Error:Execution failed for task ':library:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: Here's what I've got just in case you need to look further into this: 
https://mega.nz/#!4xRxzLxR!w1cfduskym966AgLyD8GYY5yTKrhgQm67OuMCVjuqZI

Comment: When I go to rebuild it always does this with the debug AndroidManifest and I don't know why. <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="Uninstall the following software, will affect the normal use"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

Answer (score 0):

Hi，I download your source ,and I found some problem:
1、your library source ,gradle file ,applicationID not modified
2、my systemOS is win10，jdk is oracle jdk8。
library's compiledversion and buildToolsVersion maybe needn't modify,but jdk maybe needed.I think so.[modified application id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkzGv.png)  and [run app successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMQnn.png)

Comment: Alright I got that all fixed now when I use the app and try to go to the settings the app crashes.